# Show that if $\forall$ $b\in B$, $f(b) \in T_y$ implies $f$ is open.

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:(X,T_x) \rightarrow (Y,T_y)$ be a map between two topological spaces. Let $B$ be a basis for $T_x.$ Show that if $\forall$ $b\in B$, $f(b) \in T_y$ then $f$ is open.

### I am just looking for a little feedback on my proof.

It is given that $B$ is a basis for $T_x$, then the union of elements of $B$ equals $T_x$. Take $U$ open in X, choose for each $x \in U$ an element $b_x$ of $B$ such that $x \in b_x \subset U$. Then $ U = \cup_{x \in U}b_x$ Then $f(U)= f(\cup_{x \in U} b_x)$. Therefore for each $b  \in B, f(b) \in T_y$

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the problem clearly. Please ignore my last comment.  With regard to your proof, we need to show if $U$ is open in $X$, then $f(U)$ is open in $Y$, i.e., if $U \in T_{x}$, then $f(U) \in T_{y}$.  So far, you've expressed $U$ as a union of basis elements.  Then, as you said, $f(U) = f( \bigcup \limits_{x \in U} b_{x})$, right?  Then you said "therefore, for each $b \in B$, $f(b) \in T_{y}$"...how does this statement follow from the previous work?  It doesn't.  But as part of the problem statement, you are supposed to *assume* $f(b) \in T_{y}$.

Comment: So your proof still needs some work.  You need to show $f(U) \in T_{y}$, which you haven't done yet.

Comment: Thank you. That is very helpful. The subtlety of assuming $f(b) \in T_y$ escaped me.

Comment: Thank you. That is very helpful. Assuming $f(b) \in T_y$ for each $b \in B$ then there exists a neighborhood $f(U)$ this is the union of all the elements $f(b)$. Since all of the $f(b)$ are the image of basis elements in $T_x$, they are also basis elements in $T_y$, i.e. they are each open in $T_y$ and as open sets their arbitrary unions are open as well. Thus $f(U)$  is open in $T_y$. Since $f$ maps open sets to open set, $f$ is open.

Comment: Wait, I'm confused with how you ended the proof.  How do you know if $b$ is a basis element of $T_{x}$, then $f(b)$ is a basis element of $T_{y}$?

Comment: I thought that it was evident that the image of the basis formed a basis in $T_y$. I could prove it by just showing that the image of the basis satisfies the axioms of a basis, then $f(b)$ would be clearly open?